# How to redirect variable into text file then sort alphabetical

Tags: bash, alphabetical

My script is to ask for input 1 upper case at a time and end with 0 invalid input will need to be displayed and display the first valid upper letter.

```
#! /bin/sh
count=0

until [[ $n =~ 0 ]]; do
    echo Inputs:
    read n
    if [[ $n =~ ^[A-Z]$ ]]; then
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        echo $n | sort > out.txt
    fi
done

echo The total number of valid input letters:
echo $count
echo " "
echo The first valid input:
head -n 1 /filepath/out.txt
```

Output:

```
Inputs:
B
Inputs:
A
Inputs:
C
Inputs:
0

The total number of valid input letters:
3

The first valid input:
C
```

Question: It should result in A.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
echo $n | sort > out.txt
```

always zaps the file `out.txt` with just the latest input.  Maybe you should use:

```
cp /dev/null out.txt   # Before the loop

echo $n | sort -o out.txt out.txt -
```

The `cp` command creates an empty file.  The `sort` command reads the existing file `out.txt` and its standard input (the new line), sorts the result and writes it out over `out.txt`.

This is OK for short inputs; it isn't very efficient if it needs to scale to thousands of lines.

Also, in Bash, you don't need to use `expr` for arithmetic:

```
((count++))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
#! /bin/sh
count=0

>out.txt
until [[ $n =~ 0 ]]; do
    read -p 'Inputs: ' n
    if [[ $n =~ ^[A-Z]$ ]]; then
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        echo $n  >> out.txt
    fi
done

echo The total number of valid input letters:
echo $count
echo " "
echo The first valid input:
sort out.txt |head -n 1
```

Output:

```
Inputs: B
Inputs: A
Inputs: C
Inputs: 0
The total number of valid input letters:
3

The first valid input:
A
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want only the smallest (in alphabet order) valid input, you don't need sort.  Here's an alternative answer not using sort but just keep the smallest valid input:

```
#!/bin/sh

count=0

until [[ $n =~ 0 ]]; do
    echo Inputs:
    read n
    if [[ $n =~ ^[A-Z]$ ]]; then
        ((count++))
        if [ -z $first ] || [ `expr $n \< $first` -eq 1 ]; then
            first=$n
        fi
    fi
done

echo The total number of valid input letters:
echo $count
echo " "
echo The first valid input:
echo $first
```